# Unfamiliar infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I came across a really unfamiliar sort of questions while studying infinite series (convergence, divergence, sum etc..).

> $$\displaystyle{1+\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\displaystyle{1+\frac{1}{\displaystyle{1+\frac{1}{1+\cdots}}}}}}}$$

Comment: These things are called [Continued Fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenRatio.html

Answer (score 2):

You can let
$$x=\displaystyle{1+\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\displaystyle{1+\frac{1}{\displaystyle{1+\frac{1}{1+\cdots}}}}}}}$$
then
$$x=1+\frac{1}{x}$$
which evaluates to
$$x=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$$since $x>0$

Comment: How did it evaluate to that..?

Comment: @O.Sin  Multiply both sides of the equation by $x$ to obtain $x^2 = x + 1$, then solve the resulting quadratic equation.  You want the positive solution.